# Log specific command and send it to specific file with (r)syslog

Tags: linux-kernel, syslog

Is it possible via `/etc/syslog.conf` to create a rule that log a specific command that user invoke and send it to a specified log file?

For example, I want that when users types `history -d` syslogd daemon log this information inside a specified file.

Is that possible? And How?

Comment: Easiest way to achieve this might be to create your own `history` command earlier in the `$PATH` and have it perform a `logger` command followed by the genuine `history` command.

Comment: The first thing that came to mind was `apparmor`. I am 98% sure that it can do it. There may be other solutions (including syslog, but …).

Answer (score 0):

No. The `history` "command" is a `bash` builtin, and `bash` does not publish its internal status.

This sounds like an XY problem. What problem are you really trying to solve?